# what is the meaning of " had she been so inclined" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

what is the meaning of " had she been so inclined" in this context?

> In these letters Kane continually reproaches Margaret with living in
>   deceit and hypocrisy. We have very few of her letters, so that we do
>   not know how far she defended herself. The compiler of the book,
>   though a non- Spiritualist, says: "Poor girl, with her simplicity,
>   ingenuousness and timidity, she could not, **had she been so inclined**,
>   have practised the slightest deception with any chance of success."
>   This testimony is valuable, as the writer was clearly intimately
>   acquainted with everyone concerned. Kane himself, writing to the
>   younger sister Kate, says: "Take my advice and never talk of the
>   spirits either to friends or strangers. You know that with all my
>   intimacy with Maggie after a whole month's trial I could make nothing
>   of them. Therefore they are a great mystery."

from http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html

Answer (score 2):

The phrase "had she been so inclined" means "[even] if she had wanted to".

The claim is made that the girl was so simple and timid that she could not have succeeded at deceiving even if she had wanted to.